# Thread use - crashing on phone, but not emulator

Tags: android

I want to do some loading of drawables and scale them before i need to use them. This is done in the end of onCreate().

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < Teams.getTeamA().size(); i++) {
                ViewGroup playerLayout = (ViewGroup) inflaterEnd.inflate(R.layout.flip_player_layout, null);
                updatePlayerLayout(playerLayout, R.drawable.card_team_blue, 0, Teams.getTeamA().get(i));
                // Adds the layout to the cardArray
                cardArray.add(playerLayout);
                // Adds the image of the playercard into the bmapArray and scales it
                bmapArray.add(scaleImage(R.drawable.card_big_anoffendedenglishman, scaleFactorDraw));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Teams.getTeamB().size(); i++) {
                ViewGroup playerLayout = (ViewGroup) inflaterEnd.inflate(R.layout.flip_player_layout, null);
                updatePlayerLayout(playerLayout, R.drawable.card_team_red, 1, Teams.getTeamB().get(i));
                cardArray.add(playerLayout);
                bmapArray.add(scaleImage(R.drawable.card_big_ancientegypt, scaleFactorDraw)); 
            }
            // End layout
            ViewGroup endLayout = (ViewGroup) inflaterEnd.inflate(R.layout.flip_start_layout, null);
            ImageView imageEnd = (ImageView) endLayout.getChildAt(0);
            imageEnd.setImageBitmap(scaleImage(R.drawable.card_big_placeholder, scaleFactorLayout));
            cardArray.add(endLayout);
        }
    }).start();


 private void updatePlayerLayout(ViewGroup playerLayout, int layoutDrawable, int teamPos, Player player)
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) playerLayout.getChildAt(0);
    image1.setImageBitmap(scaleImage(layoutDrawable, scaleFactorLayout));

    // CardBack
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) ((ConstraintLayout) playerLayout.getChildAt(4)).getChildAt(0);
    image3.setImageBitmap(scaleImage(R.drawable.card_big_cardback_beta, scaleFactorDraw));
```

This works fine on my emulator, and doesn't cause my app to crash. The problem comes when i load the app on my phone. 
It loads the activity, but after a couple of seconds i get the message "YourApp has stopped".

When i restrict the work of the thread (Lower TeamA and TeamB size) down to 1 each, the app works as intended.

I have tried to divide the tasks up into multiple threads and i have tried to use AsyncTask but nothing seems to work. What am i missing?

Comment: Post your log output please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load an image into ImageView can consumes lots of memory.You may use a debugger monitoring your phone,check if it throws an OutOfMemoryError when crashes.
and there are some libraries for loading images with better memory management,such as Glide.

Comment: Just debugged it on my phone and it was an OutOfMemoryError. Thank you for the fast answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an OutOfMemoryError. The fix i used was to apply the following code to the Manifest.xml file:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```